# Nslog imagename in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays

I have an `NSArray` with images. Image names is A,B,C,D. I need to `NSLog` the names of these images from the array

```
NSLog(@"Name == %@", [Array objectAtIndex:1]);
```

What do I have to use instead of this?

Comment: What's work withe the code in your code, that is the way you get an object from an array. except that you did not use the correct method [`objectAtIndex:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABDJBFC) and not `Objectatindex`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `UIImage` doesn't store its file name, if you want to keep track of the names of the files they were created from, you will need to store them as well.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by wattson, it is not possible. For this you need to take another array wherein you can save the **imageName**. Else you can take a `NSMutableDictionary` and save **imageName** as key and **Array** object as its object which you can read later.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you cannot get image file's name from `UIImage` object. If you do want to do this, you can store the name together with the image into a `NSDictionary` object:

```
NSArray * imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A.png", @"B.png", @"C.png", nil];
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[imageNames count]];
for (NSString * imageName in imageNames)
  [array addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:imageName], @"image", imageName, @"name", nil]];
```

then you can log it like:

```
NSLog(@"name = %@", [[array objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you override the "description" method of your Array  with the name of your images concatenated,it could work fine.

NSLog works in this case by asking each object for a string that describes itself, sending the -description method to the objects. (Note: if an object doesn't override the description method, you will get the -description implementation inherited from NSObject, which tends to be like . See UsingTheDescriptionMethod

**Note**: the description method should only be used for debugging purposes

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. If A,B,C,D are instance vars, they are the only thing you can control, like

```
if ((UIImage*)[Array Objectatindex:1] == A) 
   bla-bla-bla you know that it's "A"
```

Once assigned, the image name cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to `NSLog` the the whole `NSArray` use this:

```
NSArray *_array = // your array
NSLog(@"array == %@", _array);
```

**UPDATE: #1**

the one of the usable way would be the following, instead of filling the `NSMutableArray` with the `UIImage` objects only, you should add 'NSDictionary' objects to the `NSMutableArray` with the following contents like this:

```
NSMutableArray *_array = [NSMutableArray array];

// you could put this part inside a loop if you like
NSString *_imagePathWithName = @"...";
UIImage *_newImage = [UIImage imageNamed:_imagePathWithName]; // when you load it from you application bundle
// or [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_imagePathWithName]; // loading from other place
NSDictionary *_imageDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_newImage, @"keyForUIImage", _imagePathWithName, @"keyForFullPathAndName", nil];
[_array addObject:_imageDictionary];
```

and when you want to read the names from your array

```
for (NSDisctionary *_dictionary in _array) {
    UIImage *_image = (UIImage *)[_dictionary valueForKey:@"keyForUIImage"];
    NSString *_fullPathWithName = (NSString *)[_dictionary valueForKey:@"keyForFullPathAndName"];
    // do whatever you'd like with the images and the path
}
```

Comment: thanks for the downvoting. :) maybe you have to specified the question normally before you look for an answer because the phrase "`NSArray` with images" does not say exactly what kind of objects you are storing in the current `NSArray`.

Comment: How does that matter holex. According to him it can be either UIImage or UIImageView. In both cases you can't get image's name.

Comment: yes, and the word "image" would also mean anything else for example strings with images' paths. the question was "I need to `NSLog` the **names**" not only **one** name as he logged in his code fragment. this question was not quite obvious.

Comment: here is the detailed answer for the asker's **real** problem. :)